# Add a menu item to CKEditor default toolbars in XPages

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, xpages

I want to add one element (button, dropdown etc) to the standard toolbar of the CKEditor. Creating the item is simple (check [this example](http://www.kuba.co.uk/blog.php?blog_id=15)). However all of the [samples](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/How-define-toolbar-buttons-CKEditor-3) then [go on](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=rich-text-editor-nsf-custom-plugin-extension) and define their own toolbar.

I want to add the new element to an existing toolbar. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Steps are required:

- get the current toolbar name (e.g. default)
- modify the array of objects in that variable (e.h. toolbar_default)

Ideally you put that code into the init function which gets the editor object of the CKEditor as parameter:

```
 var config = editor.config;
 var toolbarName = config.toolbar;
 config["toolbar_"+toolbarName].push({"name" : "ANewName", "items" : ["yourCustomFunction"] });
```

`name` and `items` are fixed, while *ANewName* and *yourCustomFunction* is what you created. `push` appends your items at the end of the toolbar, but you can put them anywhere using standard array manipulation methods.